# Apache Spark on EMR 10 node cluster for 150TB of data not completing

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-s3, bigdata

I have a S3 bucket, from which I am taking data and saving it to HDFS on different EMR cluster. I read these stored files stored on HDFS from Apache Spark and perform some joins and data filtering, finally I save the resultant dataset of around 150TB in CSV format on HDFS.
The operation is taking forever.
I am using 64 executor, with executor memory of 120GB and driver memory of 100GB. I am using databricks for saving the data in CSV.

Rest of the hadoop setting of EMR cluster on which Spark is running are default.

While running the spark-submit I gets the following error:

```
ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 5 on ip-xx-xx-xx.ec2.internal: Container marked as failed: container_14687884542720_0157_01_000006 on host: ip-xx-xx-xx.ec2.internal. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
Killed by external signal
```

Kindly point me in right direction, to fix this

Comment: Correct, I have edited the question, with the error message

Comment: This is still salvageable with the given info